# Color calibration with a color chart

Tags: color-correction, color

Even if I set up a custom white balance in my software (with the traditional way to do it, using a *grey card* or *white balance card*, etc.), sometimes the colors are not exactly like I would like.

I would like to be able to :

- shoot a color chart with **normalized colors** (example: [GretagMacbeth](http://www.ephotozine.com/articles/Kodak-EasyShare-V803-8mp-5253/images/kodak_V803_colour_chart.jpg))
- import this video in Premiere (or any other software), and match all colors between left and right panel :

[image]

Then the colors would be really calibrated.

**Does such a tool exist?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any that work directly in Premiere, however I can use my Spyder Checkr24 to either adjust my videos in Adobe Lightroom or DaVinci Resolve.  For Lightroom, I use the software that came with my Spyder Checkr to make a preset I can apply.  In Resolve, there is actually built in native support for working with the swatches.

There are also other third party tools available that I haven't really looked in to, so I can't say for certain that there isn't a way to do it directly in Premiere with a third party tool, but the way I've been doing it has worked well enough that I have not bothered to look any further in to doing it directly in Premiere.

For more details on how things work in Resolve, you can check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onom8tpiof8) or if you have a decent idea about how to use Resolve already, take note of the steps in this screenshot.  Start with 0 by choosing the target you are using on the Color workspace.  Then select the color match grid tool on the preview screen(1).  Position the grid over your color target during a portion of the clip that has the target visible (2).  Finally, hit Match(3) in order to have it generate the color correction profile for the clip.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What's your workflow in DaVinci Resolve to calibrate colors with a video you've shot of your Spyder Checkr24 color chart? Would you have a small screenshot, I would be interested.   (PS: do you use DaVinci Lite / free version?)

Comment: Yes, I use the free version. I'll try to post a screenshot and more details tonight when I'm actually home.

Comment: @Basj - see the update above.  Sorry about the delay.